# Fluent nhibernate configuration error using web.config

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, web-config

Hi im new in fluent nhibernate:
I get an error when configure db conection using web.config
The error is "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used.."

Web.config:

```
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Connection1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Server=local;Database=aDataBase;User ID=aUser;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>
```

My fluent configuration:

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
        .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Connection1")).ShowSql() )
        .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Car>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

It works if I use

```
   .ConnectionString(@"Server=local;Database=aDataBase;User ID=aUser;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;"
```

but I want to get the connection string from Web.config (not Hard-coded).

thanks.

Comment: your solution works for me, you probably have problem elsewhere, try checking inner exception.

Comment: Something like this should work:-.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ConfigurationManager object to acces your connection string. Something like this should work:

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString).ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Car>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```